# Can java be used to creating File formats, if not what Languages are suitable?

Tags: java, android

I do not know if this is the right place to ask this question, but I have been wondering, what languages can one use to create a file format, I am working on an android app which reads and writes files, I want to create a unique file format which it only can read, I know each format uses different algorithms, that is why am asking if anyone knows any references I can look at, I can not seem to find any documentation online on this topic.

Comment: for example we have .txt, .psd, that is what i mean by file formats

Comment: Yes, just give the filename with it's extension. `File file = new File("C://file.xyz");`

Comment: You can design a file format with a pen and paper. Just decide what the bytes inside the file mean. Class file for example start with the hex digits `0xCAFEBABE`. It has no other functionality than to identify the file as a Java class file.

Comment: @Kayaman I read somewhere and someone was using java, but the tutorial was not complete,if you don not mind, i would like any reference

Comment: @Chrome You don't "program" file formats. You decide how the file is layed out, then you write code to read/write data into those formats. There's no tutorials about creating file formats. They're just agreements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any language can be used to create any kind of files if you know the encoding and encryption type of those file formats. If you really need a unique type of file for your application, simply save serialized objects or encrypt and save the serialized stream and use any desired extension.

Comment: do you have any kind of documentation? i need some sort of tutorial, I understand better with tutorials.

Comment: I don't have tutorials right now. Give me some time I will post an article on my blog and let you know.